# Checkbox change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chk').live('change', function() {
      alert('change event fired');
    });
    $('a').click(function() {
      $('.chk').attr('checked', true);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chkHolder">
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="a" id="a" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="b" id="b" />
</div>
<a href="#">check all</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the "check all" hyperlink, I want the change event fired for each of the checkboxes. However, that is not happening.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the page reloading instead? You might need a `return false;` or [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the `click()` hander

Answer (score 34, accepted):

use: `$('.chk').attr('checked', true).change();`

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/NRPSA/1/

Comment: Does anyone know why we need to do it explicitly.

Comment: @lulalala because no event is invoked on that element, it is just setting a property. `change()` triggers the change event.

Answer (score 7):

When you change the attribute also use the following:

```
$('.chk').trigger('change');
```

Or in your code like other people have suggested:

```
$('.chk').attr('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
$('a').click(function() {
      $('.chk').attr('checked', true);
});
```

To -

```
$('a').click(function() {
      $('.chk').attr('checked', true).trigger('change');
 });
```

That should force a trigger of the 'change' event.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/pwmBE/

Comment: remember that jquery you can chain commands, you don't need to find .chk two times

Comment: @voigtan - Thanks, I completely missed that. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<div id ="chkall"> <a href="#">check all</a> <div>

            $('#chkall a').live("change", function() {
            $('.chk').attr('checked', true);
            });
```