# call change() event handler if I select radio button programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have HTML like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="FL" checked="checked" />Fixed
<input type="radio" name="type" value="SV" />Saving
<input type="radio" name="type" value="L2" />Type 2
```

And following script

```
$(function () {
        $('input[name=type]').change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
        $('input[value=SV]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
```

Firstly, have added a change event to radio button.
change event handler triggered if I am selecting radio button from UI.
But it does not triggered when I change selected radio button value pro-grammatically.

**I want `change event` also to be triggered when I select radio button pro-grammatically.**

Comment: You choose a bad nickname. what will you do next year...?

Comment: I will change it to my real name after a few days only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkbox change event not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387531/checkbox-change-event-not-firing) ... please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: @new to stackoverflow, adding a comment to every response asking for upvote isn't a good policy and won't get you more upvotes; asking a good question will. And your comments may get flagged.

Comment: @FlomEnol Dear, sorry for that..bt that tym I could not even vote up answers. Thats because I did it. Now I hv removed any such cmnts. Sorry again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `trigger()` to programmatically raise an event:

```
$(function () {
  $('input[name="type"]').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
  $('input[value="SV"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't change automatically. You have to do one of the following:

either

```
$('input[value=SV]').attr('checked', 'checked').trigger("change")
```

or

```
$('input[value=SV]').attr('checked', 'checked').change();
```

Comment: Thanks @FreeCandies I like 2nd method u describe.